# Terraform CICD pipeline GCP

Tags: github, jenkins, google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, terraform

I am new to terraform and I want set up a CI/CD pipeline to GCP  with github to replace a current system  that use's jenkins, as we want to increase automation of deployments. What would be the best way or architecture to  do this.

Comment: There are a super rich set of curated articles all on CI as documented here:

https://www.gcpweekly.com/gcp-resources/tag/ci/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the primary products related to CI/CD is Google's Cloud Build.

https://cloud.google.com/build

It's one liner reads:

> Build, test, and deploy on our serverless CI/CD platform.

It has built in triggers that include GitHub integration meaning that when events occur on GitHub, Cloud Build runs its prescribed recipes.

I'd suggest reading the documenation found at the above page and also correlate against the curated documentation found on GCP Weekly here:

- [Tag: CI](https://www.gcpweekly.com/gcp-resources/tag/ci/)
- [Tag: Cloud Build](https://www.gcpweekly.com/gcp-resources/tag/cloud-build/)